# How to use context path while importing CSS and JS files in ADF faces?

Tags: jsp, jsf-1.2, oracle-adf, jspx

I have a project requirement that has to migrate a JSP file using JSF 1.2 faces to JSPX using ADF faces. I am facing issues in the part where I have to import external CSS and JS files

Eg: I must convert this to ADF

```
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"        href='<h:outputText
> value="#{utils.portletContextPath}"/>css/calendar.css' /> <script
> type="text/javascript"        src='<h:outputText
> value="#{utils.portletContextPath}"/>js/calendar/calendar.js'></script>
```

The thing is I have to use a CSS/ JS file in a common folder on the server external to the application.

Tried many ways but always get the below error:
**Its illegal to specify deferred expression for dynamic attribute.**

Any pointers for resolutions would be great.

Thanks,
Sandesh

Answer (score 0):

Try use the af:resource tag. here is [the reference](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_resource.html)

Comment: I was trying by using af:resouorce tags. But as my tags are using a value thats dynamically calculated(The #{utils.portletContextPath} part), I am not able to do this. I understand that if I give the relative path directly here, it will  to work, but that not what I am trying to do.

Comment: <af:resource type="css" source="#{utils.portletContextPath}/css/calendar.css'"/>